# PHP if statement - either but not both

Tags: php

What's the correct way to rephrase this statement so that it passes if either variable is set, but not if BOTH are set?

```
if (isset($_GET['txnid']) || isset($_GET['complete'])){
```

Comment: you need the xor operator

Comment: [XOR Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: Thanks both - exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, its called an XOR, it will be true if either one of them is true, but not both.

```
if (isset($_GET['txnid']) XOR isset($_GET['complete'])){
```

Source: [PHP: Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: XOR is known as the eXclusive OR operator.